# How do I randomly pick every color from my array only once without using classes

Tags: arrays, random

For my assignment I have to create the game 'memory'. I keep getting stuck on the part where I randomly give every card a color.

I first created this array

```
int rectColorArray[] ={BROWN, BROWN,WHITE, WHITE,RED, RED, GREEN, GREEN};
```

And made a loop in which I hoped it would only pick each color once.

```
void drawCards(int rectColor){
  int length = 50;
  int xPos =0;
  int yPos =0;
 
  for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
    rectColor = rectColorArray[(int)random(0,rectColorArray.length)];
    fill(rectColor);
   rect(xPos,yPos, length, length); 
   xPos = xPos + length + 10;   
    splice(rectColorArray,i,1);
  }
}
```

it seems as if 'splice' doesn't do anything, because I keep getting rects that doesn't give the wanted output.

So my final question is: Does anyone know how to fix this problem, or if I should use another technique?

Comment: This ain't [tag:javascript] and `{BROWN, BROWN,WHITE, WHITE,RED, RED, GREEN, GREEN}` does not create an array, but an object in JS. Is this [tag:java]?

Comment: `I keep getting stuck on the part where I randomly give every card a color.` How about a different approach: shuffle the array of colors and then hand out the colors in order.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I wrongly put the js tag. Retracted it.

Answer (score 1):

A very common solution to this sort of problem is to *shuffle* the source array, then simply use the shuffled items one at a time sequentially.

[How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)